# JavaScript getMonth() returns 50 for the month value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning gang.

I have a jQuery Datepicker object that is prepoulated using a javscript Date object, and I have getMonth() returning 50 as the month, instead of 5.  This was previously working as recent as 4/27/2012.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#datepicker1').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

var press_date = new Date(); //This is the Date object that you're getting from external source

$('#datepicker1').val(press_date.getFullYear()+'-'
                     +press_date.getMonth()+1+'-'
                     +press_date.getDate());

$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
                     showAnim:'slide',showOn: 'button',
                     dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                     buttonImage: 'images/calendar.jpg',
                     buttonImageOnly: true,onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {} 
                    });
$('#datepicker').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
                     showAnim:'slide',showOn: 'button',
                     dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                     buttonImage: 'images/calendar.jpg',
                     buttonImageOnly: true,onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {} 
                    });
});
```

My guess is that this is a simple issue to resolve, but I haven't seen anything around the web to explain it.

Comment: Try putting `press_date.getMonth()+1` in parentheses.

Comment: 1+"1"+2+"3" => 1123 in js. `press_date.getFullYear()+'-'                   +press_date.getMonth()+1+'-'+press_date.getDate()` so as this. Try using proper paranthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the x.getMonth()+1 in your expression. Since you are concatenating strings the parser is getting confused. You can surround the x.getMonth()+1 in parenthesis or just move that calculation outside of the string concatenation:

For example, surround it with parenthesis:

`x.getFullYear()+'-'+(x.getMonth()+1)+'-'+x.getDate()`

**UPDATE:** To get the month value zero padded I would definitively move the calculation to its own line to make it clear:

```
month = x.getMonth() + 1; 
monthString = month < 9 ? '0' + month : month; 
dbDate = x.getFullYear() + '-' + monthString + '-' + x.getDate();
```

Comment: This fixed the month problem.  However, this date is going into a db table, and I can't send 2012-6-25.  My guess is that I need to do some "code gymnastics" to get the 0 in front of the 6 (or any other single digit months), correct?

Comment: Hector, I have it padded now, albeit in a bulkier manner (codewise).  However, when I "view source" on the page, it shows up blank, so if the user doesn't actually populate the field via the datepicker, nothing is sent, and that means bad business for me.  I will not populate the field and make it required.  Is that good or bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the part of your code that adds one to the month in parentheses, so JavaScript interprets + in the mathematical sense instead of for string concatenation:

```
$('#datepicker1').val(press_date.getFullYear() + '-' + 
                     (press_date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + 
                     press_date.getDate());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/B53u3/